# How can I upgrade the java version in a AWS instance to 1.8?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, version

Currently, I have some automation scripts which spins up an instance to do stuff; but it needs java 1.8. The default java version seems to be 1.6. Is there any way in the cloud formation script or instance settings which I can upgrade/set the java version to 1.8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to create a script that automates the following. Once you start a script update if your having any issues. You will want to save the script in an S3 bucket.

http://tecadmin.net/install-java-8-on-centos-rhel-and-fedora/

Answer (score 7):

install Java 1.8

```
sudo yum install java-1.8.0
```

change Java version

```
sudo alternatives --config java
```